# How to show that if $24k+4$ and $24k+1$ are both perfect squares where $k$ is a natural number, then it is only when $k=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I am trying to show that if $24k+4$ and $24k+1$ are both perfect squares where $k$ is a natural number, then the only possibility is when $k=0$.

Here is how I did it:
Let $24k+4=x^2$ and $24k+1=y^2$, then $x^2=y^2+3$. So the problem reduces to finding solution for the equation $x^2=y^2+3$. One solution is $x=2$ and $y=1$, which implies $k=0$.

My question is:
But how do we know that $x=2$ and $y=1$ is the only solution? Is there any way for us to show that it is the only solution? Also, how can we solve this kind of equation in general?

Thanks!

Comment: Similar to some of the answer below, but this may help you as well: Note that if $x<y$ are natural numbers, then $y^2-x^2\ge (x+1)^2-x^2=2x+1$. If $x=24k+1\ge 1$, then $2x+1\ge 3$, and it follows that $k=0$, $x=1$, and $y=x+1=2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Your equation can be rewritten as $x^2-y^2=3$... but $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$. What values can the (integers!) $x-y$ and $x+y$ take, in this case?

Comment: Ah, why couldn't I realise that! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

As $x,y$ are integers, so will be $x\pm y$

$$(x+y)(x-y)=3\implies x-y=\frac3{x+y}$$ which is an integer

Now what are the (integer) divisors of $3$?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-algebraic way of seeing this.
For $f(x)=x^2$, the derivative $f'(x)=2x$,that is rate of chjange is higher as $x$ in creases. So if two squares differ by $3$, at some point then there is no hope of finding further example of squares with such close distance.

Comment: and also very informal as it's written